# Коррекция позиции редактируемого текстового контроля не работает в iOS8?

Tags: objective-c, ios

У меня код который меняет позицию редактируемого поля так что бы оно не было скрыто клавиатурой. Код работает под iOS7 но перестал работать под iOS8. Какова причина? Как устранить?

Вот мой код:

```
- (void) keyboardShow: (NSNotification*) n {
    self->_oldContentInset = self.tvPayments.contentInset;
    self->_oldIndicatorInset = self.tvPayments.scrollIndicatorInsets;
    self->_oldOffset = self.tvPayments.contentOffset;

    NSDictionary* d = [n userInfo];
    CGRect r = [[d objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    r = [self.tvPayments convertRect:r fromView:nil];
    CGRect f = self.fr.frame;
    CGFloat y =
    CGRectGetMaxY(f) + r.size.height -
    self.tvPayments.bounds.size.height + 5;
    if (r.origin.y < CGRectGetMaxY(f)) {
        NSNumber* duration = d[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
        NSNumber* curve = d[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:duration.floatValue
                              delay:0
                            options:curve.integerValue << 16
                         animations:^{
                             CGRect b = self.tvPayments.bounds;
                             b.origin = CGPointMake(0, y);
                             self.tvPayments.bounds = b;
                         } completion: nil];
    }
    UIEdgeInsets insets = self.tvPayments.contentInset;
    insets.bottom = r.size.height;
    self.tvPayments.contentInset = insets;
    insets = self.tvPayments.scrollIndicatorInsets;
    insets.bottom = r.size.height;
    self.tvPayments.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets;
}

- (void) keyboardHide: (NSNotification*) n {
    NSNumber* duration = n.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSNumber* curve = n.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration.floatValue
                          delay:0
                        options:curve.integerValue << 16
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect b = self.tvPayments.bounds;
                         b.origin = self->_oldOffset;
                         self.tvPayments.bounds = b;
                         self.tvPayments.scrollIndicatorInsets = self->_oldIndicatorInset;
                         self.tvPayments.contentInset = self->_oldContentInset;

                     } completion:nil];
}
```

У мена тоже есть нотификация:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Анимирование контроллов синхронно с клавиатурой - неблагодарное занятие, нотификации иногда шлются не к месту, не всегда с правильными значениями фреймов, есть нюансы со сменой ориентации (абсолютно разные для iOS7 и iOS8), а в iOS8 к клавиатуре так же добавилась плашка с рекомендациями для быстрого набора текста на английском, которую можно скрывать/показывать свайпом по ней.

Лучше всего все это мракобесие разложено по полочкам [здесь](http://smnh.me/synchronizing-rotation-animation-between-the-keyboard-and-the-attached-view-part-2/). Пользовался этим кодом, все работает прекрасно, только нужно учесть, что при незаконченном жесте swipe to back (когда начали свайп с левого края экрана, но передумали и вернули контроллер на место) `-viewWillAppear` и `-viewDidDisappear` не будут вызываться равное количество раз, и можно случайно подписаться на `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` несколько раз с печальными последствиями.

Comment: Спасибо большое - про мракобесие знаю - второе приложение мучает. Сейчас попробую. Очень странно, что управление клавиатурой в этом случае ручное (а не автоматическое).

Answer (score 0):

Я решаю эту проблему достаточно просто с помощью auto layout. Полю задаю констрейнт с отступом до низа и в начале фазы показа клавиатуры просто анимирую увеличение константы у констрейнта. Анимация происходит достаточно плавно, никакого мракобесия не замечал. Пример можно посмотреть в моём классе [SZAutogrowTextView](https://github.com/Sega-Zero/SZAutogrowTextView), я сделал семпл как раз с таким подходом.